# Loopback3: Reset password flow - how to check if token expired

Tags: loopback

So I am a bit confused on how to end my reset password flow

1. I have created a form to request a reset password, where user enters his email (post [users/reset](http://users/reset))
2. I have the **resetPasswordRequest** which sends the email to the user with reset link ([mydomain/users/reset/:access_token](http://mydomain/users/reset/:access_token))
3. I created the form with new password(s) field that then calls the final endpoint (post u[sers/reset-password](http://users/reset-password)).

Now, the problem is when user comes to the form on number 3. I would like to check if the access token passed in the url is still valid before even displaying the form... so if it was already "redeemed" or it is ttl-d... inform the user to request another one... before wasting the time on entering the new password

so how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Simple just make an API call when you are on form-3 where you need to validate the token. Below is the code for validating the token :

```
  User.validateAccessToken = function (options, callback) {
    return (options.accessToken != null)
      ? callback(null, { id: options.accessToken.id })
      : callback(getErrorMessage('AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED'));
  };

  User.remoteMethod('validateAccessToken', {
    http: {
      verb: 'get',
      path: '/validateAccessToken'
    },
    accepts: [{ arg: 'options', type: 'object', http: 'optionsFromRequest' }],
    returns: {
      arg: 'result',
      type: 'object'
    }
  });
```